# How to get strftime to output yearly quarters?

Tags: python, pandas, strftime

I am trying to create a list of year-quarters in python; per the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html), `%q` (I believe) should output an integer representation of calendar quarter, but instead the output I get is just `%q` literally.

Input:

```
pd.date_range('2021-01-01','2022-01-01',freq='Q').strftime('%Y-%q').tolist()
```

Expected Output:

```
['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04']
```

Actual Output:

```
['2021-%q', '2021-%q', '2021-%q', '2021-%q']
```

Comment: The code you provided does not display the "actual output" you're showing

Comment: `pd.PeriodIndex(pd.date_range('2021-01-01','2022-01-01',freq='Q')).strftime('%Y-%q').tolist()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%q` formatter is specific to [`Period.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html), so it must be used with `Period` data:

> The method recognizes the same directives as the [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) function of the standard Python distribution, **as well as the specific additional directives `%f`, `%F`, `%q`.**

Either create a [`period_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) directly (but note that it includes the end date, unlike `date_range`):

```
periods = pd.period_range('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01', freq='Q')
# PeriodIndex(['2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2021Q4', '2022Q1'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]')

periods.strftime('%Y-0%q').tolist()
# ['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04', '2022-01']
```

Or convert an existing `DatetimeIndex` to a [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html):

```
dates = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01', freq='Q')
# DatetimeIndex(['2021-03-31', '2021-06-30', '2021-09-30', '2021-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='Q-DEC')

pd.PeriodIndex(dates).strftime('%Y-0%q').tolist()
# ['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04']
```